# Unable to instantiate application java.lang.RuntimeException:...BackupDB cannot be cast to android.app.Application

Tags: java, android, android-intent

MANIFEST:(partial view)
  MainActivity, program immediately terminates and issues the messages in the Log.
  It should have started showing the buttons to select options to continue execution. 
  After days of  researching this forum, I found postings that suggest to place the BackupDb inside the application in the Manifest.
  After doing that, I ended up with the message in the log.
  Having exhausted my research venues, I'd like to know what could be the problem and how to solve it.

MANIFEST:(partial view)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.peter.databasetest"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="16"
  android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <supports-screens
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:smallScreens="false"
  />

  <application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
  **android:name="com.peter.databasetest.BackupDB">**

  <activity
  android:name="com.peter.databasetest.MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity
  android:name=".CheckDatabase"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHECKDATABASE" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>  

  <activity
  android:name=".CheckSDcard"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHECKSDCARD" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>  

  <activity
  android:name="com.peter.databasetest.Insert"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.peter.databasetest.INSERT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  </application>
   </manifest>
```

MainActivity: Calls checkSDcard and CheckDatabase. Checks if there is SDCard present and the database in main, exists.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    DBAdapter db;
    Button insertButton;                      //ADD A NEW RECORD
    Button listAllButton;                      //LIST ALL 
    Button cancelButton;                     //CANCEL PGM
    Button  backupDbButton;          //REQUEST BACKUP DB TO SDCARD
    Button restoreButton;                   //RESTORE DB FROM SDCARD TO MAIN
    Button memsizeButton;               //SHOW MEMORY SIZES ON  DEVICE

    int retcode;
    int chk;
    String message;
    public Context context;
    public  static final  String NO_DB ="Database does not exist. Backup is not possible";
    public  static final  String DB_PB ="ERROR- Check log";
    public  static final  String UNWR_SDCARD ="Your SDCard must be set to writable. Check the card lock";
    public  static final  String NO_SDCARD ="No SDcard detected. No backup is possible";
    public  static final  String BKP_OK = "Backup was SUCCESSFUL.";
    public  static final  String BKP_NOK = "Backup FAILED. "; 
                static final     int SD_CHECK = 1; 
                static final     int DB_CHECK = 2; 
                static final     int BK_CHECK = 3; 

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        insertButton            = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insertButton);
        listAllButton               = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listAllButton);
        cancelButton            = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
         backupDbButton     = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backupDbButton);
         restoreButton          = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restoreButton);
         memsizeButton            = (Button) findViewById(R.id. memsizeButton);


        insertButton.setOnClickListener(this);              //insert record  into DB
        listAllButton.setOnClickListener(this);             //list ALL records from DB
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);              //cancel the program
        backupDbButton.setOnClickListener(this);        //request backup to sdcard
        restoreButton.setOnClickListener(this);            //request restore from sdcard
        memsizeButton.setOnClickListener(this);        //Get Meory sizes


    public void onClick(View v ) {

        if (v  == insertButton) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Insert.class));

        }else if (v  == listAllButton){
                    startActivity (new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListDr.class)); 

        }else if (v  == backupDbButton){             
            **Intent checksd = new Intent(this,CheckSDcard.class);**
            **startActivityForResult(checksd,  SD_CHECK);**              

        }else if (v ==  restoreButton) {
                    startActivity (new Intent(MainActivity.this,RestoreDB.class));

        }else if (v ==  memsizeButton) {
                startActivity (new Intent(MainActivity.this,GetMemorySizes.class));

         }else if (v  == cancelButton){   
                 finish();
                } 
       }  
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == SD_CHECK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    Intent checkdb = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CheckDatabase.class);
                    startActivityForResult(checkdb,  DB_CHECK);              

            }else if (requestCode == DB_CHECK && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                    **Intent backup = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BackupDB.class);**
                    **startActivityForResult(backup, BK_CHECK);**       

            }else if (requestCode == BK_CHECK && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    message = BKP_OK;
                    SendMessageDialog(message);
                    finish();
            } 
                if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && resultCode == -1){ 
                    message = NO_DB;                                                     
                    SendMessageDialog(message); 
                    finish();

                }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && resultCode == -2) { 
                    message = DB_PB;                                                 
                    SendMessageDialog(message); 
                    finish();
                } 
            }
```

BackupDb: Copies the database to the SDCARD.

```
  package com.peter.databasetest;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import com.peter.databasetest.DBAdapter;

public  class BackupDB extends  AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> { 

    DBAdapter db;
    intrc= -10;
    intretcode;
    intchk;
    Stringmessage;
    String mypackage;
    public Context context; 
    public static  String FOLDER_NAME = "DBfolder";
    public  static  final  String DATABASE_NAME = "UserDB.db";
    public  static  final  String DATABASE_BACKUP= "UserDB.db";
    public  static final  String BKP_OK = "Backup was SUCCESSFUL.";
    public  static final  String BKP_NOK = "Backup FAILED. ";

    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    //  GET PACKAGE NAME
    mypackage = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() ;
    }
    //     START BACKUP TO SDCARD

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

    //    DOING BACKUP

    Log.i("00000" , "STARTING BACKUP...BACKUP ");
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory(); 

    CREATE A FOLDER   /mnt/sdcard<packagename>FOLDER_NAME if it does not exist  

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()   
    + "/"
    + mypackage 
    + "/" 
    + FOLDER_NAME);
    if(!folder.exists()) {
    if (folder.mkdirs()) ;
    }                                   

    // GET THE PATH OF THE BACKUP ON THE SDCARD

    FilefileBackupDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
    + "/"
    +mypackage 
    + "/"
    + FOLDER_NAME
    +"/"
    + DATABASE_BACKUP) ;

    // IF WE HAVE A BACKUP ON SDCARD, DELETE IT TO MAKE ROOM FOR THE NEW  BACKUP

    if (fileBackupDir.exists()) {
    fileBackupDir.delete(); 
    }else { 
    * DO NOTHING */
    } 
    //   GET CURRENT DB PATH FOR THE COPY         
    String currentDBPath = "/data/" + mypackage  + "/databases/"+ DATABASE_NAME;         
    //   GET CURRENT DB PATH FOR THE BACKUP          
    String backupDBPath =  "/" + mypackage  + "/"  +FOLDER_NAME + "/" + DATABASE_BACKUP; 

    FilecurrDB  = new File(data,  currentDBPath)  ;         
    FilebkpDB   = new File(sd,  backupDBPath);

    FileChannel from = null;
    try {
    from = new FileInputStream(currDB).getChannel();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileChannel to = null;
    try {
    to = new FileOutputStream(bkpDB).getChannel();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    try {
    to.transferFrom(from, 0, from.size());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    try {
    from.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
    to.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    retcode = 0;

    returnretcode;          
    //  end DoInBackgroung

    protectedvoid onPostExecute(Integer retcode, String message) {
    if(retcode == 0) {
    message = BKP_OK;
    SendMessageDialog(message);
    }else {
    message = BKP_NOK;
    SendMessageDialog(message);
    }
    }  
    public  void SendMessageDialog(String message) {
    if  (message == BKP_OK ) {   
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
    builder.setTitle("My Database")
    .setMessage(message)      // Title of the dialog 
    .setCancelable(true)     // Does  allow the use of Back Button on the hardware
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ecg)//  da picture
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public  void  onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
    dialog.dismiss();
    dialog.cancel(); 
    }                 
    });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); 
    alert.show();        
    }else {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    builder.setTitle("My Database")
    .setMessage(message)      // Title of the dialog 
    .setCancelable(true)     // Does  allow the use of Back Button on the hardware
    .setIcon(R.drawable.bad)//  da picture
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public  void  onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
    dialog.dismiss();
    dialog.cancel(); 
    }                 
    });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    }
    }
    }
```

Logcat:

```
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.peter.databasetest.BackupDB:     
  : com.peter.databasetest.BackupDB cannot be cast to  android.app.Application
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4124)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.peter.databasetest.BackupDB cannot be cast to android.app.Application
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:967)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
  02-12 07:36:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(987):    ... 11 more
```

Comment:
 I removed the BackupDb from the application and reinstated it as activity.

```
<activity
android:name=".BackupDB"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action  android:name="com.peter.databasetest.BACKUPDB" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The program now brings up the buttons as expected, but when trying the backup I still get the same message as in the earlier log.  (Catch-22?)

Most current log:

```
  02-12 13:00:16.569: W/dalvikvm(30656): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity      ComponentInfo{com.peter.databasetest/com.peter.databasetest.BackupDB}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.peter.databasetest.BackupDB cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.peter.databasetest.BackupDB cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
  02-12 13:00:16.650: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):  ... 11 more




>Question:
>Is there any known limitation calling an AsyncTask by way of startActivityForResult? 
>Could this be a factor?
```

Comment: **android:name="com.peter.databasetest.BackupDB">** here you are saying to the Android that your class BackupDP extends Application, is that true?

Comment: I don't know based on what they suggested you to reference the `BackupDb` in the manifest file as application name, but taking in consideration that `BackupDb` is an AsyncTask, it surely shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the Manifest file, you are setting your application:name to be te BackupDB class and this class is only an AsyncTask not an Application.

As can be seen on the explanation of "android:name":

> An optional name of a class implementing the overall
>   android.app.Application for this package. [string]